# How do I iterate over JSON children in python?

Tags: python, json, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to iterate over a JSON response from google sheets API. My goal is to get the values of each title ('Chapter 1', 'Chapter 2', etc...), but I cannot further iterate past the first child of the object.

I'm trying to parse through [this response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXK4C.png)

This is what I currently have:

```py
request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, ranges=ranges, includeGridData=include_grid_data)
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)
    for x in response['sheets']:
        print(response['properties']['title'])
```

And it returns only `少女終末旅行 Volume 1 Vocab`(as to be expected, as it iterator isn't used).

If I add an index after 'title', it returns the character at the index of that iterator. If I put it all into `response['sheets']['properties']['title']` , it throws `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Please add your data as formatted text, not as a linked image.

Comment: In your for loop, you should work on `x` not `response`. `print(x['properties']['title'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you should be working on the `x` variable, not on `response`

```
for x in response['sheets']:
    print(x['properties']['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:-

```
# Codes ...
print(response)
for sheet in response['sheets']:
  print(sheet['properties']['title'])
```

Once you are using `for x in y` then you have to use `x` to get further values.

Answer (score 0):

You could write print(response[x]) not the response[properties][title]

Or

You can write x["name].

Please let me know if you have any questions. I would be very happy to help you on this.

Comment: Have you even tried your first "impossible" option?